Count mismatch in AKHQ UI 0.24.0
I am producing 10 records to kafka topic and able to consume all 10 but in AKHQ UI I am seeing count as 12 . If I count the values manually its 10 only (same as what's produced).
PFA

Tried changing sort Order to newest but didn't help .
Also observed 12 data is shown in offset when checked in data 153-161 offset have only 7 records and 132-136 have only 3 records (please refer image 3 )



Transaction markers are unique offsets in Kafka that'll automatically be skipped by consumers, but naive offset counting cannot exclude them

Thanks OneCricketeer for clarifying , Can these Transcation messages be excluded from total topic count displayed in akhq ?

I'm not sure. Technically, the count is correct. You've sent 10 records, surrounded by a start and end marker. Therefore it's 12 offsets. Feel free to ask the developer https://github.com/tchiotludo/akhq/issues

Otherwise, in general, using offsets is never a reliable way to find the size of a topic, due to background retention jobs, topic compaction, potentially corrupt log segments, etc
